# Could not find an application at the specified director xamarin ios app

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

Has anyone ever come across the error

```
Log generated on 29/12/2014 00:12:01

Failed to deploy application on the target device. Please try to rebuild the solution and try again. (Generic)
OK

Build server returned an Error.

error MT1001: Could not find an application at the specified directory

error MT1001: Could not find an application at the specified directory
```

I am trying to run the ios app sample project [here](http://nullskull.com/a/10476786/xamarin-cross-platform-application-consuming-wcf--part-2.aspx)

I am using Visual Studio 2013 I dont have much else to go on here really

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the error message in the Error Message List of Visual Studio to see details.
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23425

Might be a problem with the Entitlements.plist